# Why WinDbg is opening as default application for crash of C++ application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, crash, windbg

I have installed WinDbg application for dump analysis and memory leaks. Whenever my application crash in Visual Studio, now WinDbg is opening as default application. I want to restore to my default behavior.

Second problem is more troubling, just for sake of testing I attached Notepad.exe with WinDbg, now every time I start notepad, or double click on text file, WinDbg starts and I need to detach process from WinDbg.

I do not know if I am doing something wrong, or it is default behavior of WinDbg.

Please suggest how to get rid of this problem.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The first problem** you have is probably caused by WinDbg installer - WinDbg became your default system debugger. Fortunately you can easily change it in the registry. Create a .reg file with the following content:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"UserDebuggerHotKey"=dword:00000000
"Debugger"="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe\" -p %ld -e %ld"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"UserDebuggerHotKey"=dword:00000000
"Debugger"="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe\" -p %ld -e %ld"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe\" PID %d APPDOM %d EXTEXT \"%s\" EVTHDL %d"
"DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting"=dword:00000010

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework]
"DbgManagedDebugger"="\"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\vsjitdebugger.exe\" PID %d APPDOM %d EXTEXT \"%s\" EVTHDL %d"
"DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting"=dword:00000010
```

and run it - this should restore the Visual Studio as a default debugger.

**The second problem** is probably related to invalid `Image File Execution Options`. Open regedit.exe and go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options` and look for notepad.exe subkey - if it's there remove it. Make also sure that it does not exist for x86: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`